# reading input testcases from a file in C from command line

Tags: c, command

currently I am using a command like the one below:

> ./code < input.txt > output.txt

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it *this* way???

Comment: There can be many different ways of doing it, what exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use file I/O operations, `fopen()`, `fclose()` and the file version of whatever you are using to read from `stdin`....`fscanf()`, `fgetc()`, `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   char str1[10], str2[10], str3[10];
   int year;
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
   fputs("We are in 2012", fp);

   rewind(fp);
   fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", str1, str2, str3, &year);

   printf("Read String1 |%s|\n", str1 );
   printf("Read String2 |%s|\n", str2 );
   printf("Read String3 |%s|\n", str3 );
   printf("Read Integer |%d|\n", year );

   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

output :

```
Read String1 |We|
Read String2 |are|
Read String3 |in|
Read Integer |2012|
```

If you want to make the code generic enough to accept input from a number of different files, you could specify the filename as a command line option.